# SublimeJava won't react at all on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: sublimetext2, code-completion

today I tried to install and run the SublimeJava Plugin for Sublime Text 2. Here is basically what i've done.

- Cloning the [git Repository](https://github.com/quarnster/SublimeJava.git) into ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages.
- Created a ProjectFile to test the Plugin.

  ```
  {
      "folders":
      [
          {
              // The class files are in the same directory
              "path": "~/src/path_to_project/"
          }
      ],

      "settings":
      [
          {
          "sublimejava_classpath":
              [
              "~/src/path_to_project/",
              "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Libraries/"
              ],
          "sublimejava_enabled":true
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

However, nothing happens when I type something that should trigger the code-completion. What am I missing?